# Why can't i show the date from a SELECT in a input type date with PHP and ORACLE?

Tags: php, oracle

I try to use the correct format for the date that I have in OracleBD and then show in a form with.

```
<input type="date"
```

but that doesn't work.

Code I'm using:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conexion, "SELECT COD_ALUMNO,NOMBRES, APELLIDOS,SEXO,TO_CHAR(NACIMIENTO, 'DD-MON-YYYY'),DIRECCION,TEL_TUTOR,COD_GRUPO FROM ALUMNOS WHERE COD_ALUMNO = :cod_alu");
```

Form:
[image]

DB part:
[image]

Record:

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038) you should use `YYYY-MM-DD` format and let the browser do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should as the name for column like this:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conexion, "SELECT COD_ALUMNO,NOMBRES, APELLIDOS,SEXO,TO_CHAR(NACIMIENTO, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS NACIMIENTO,DIRECCION,TEL_TUTOR,COD_GRUPO FROM ALUMNOS WHERE COD_ALUMNO = :cod_alu");
```